# Am getting java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 220: while running a test in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to pass the below line in my URL

```
metadata={"occasion":[{"metavalue":"day-casual"}],"fit":[{"metavalue":"slim"}]}
```

But when I run the test, am getting error as below

> java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 220: 
>        at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848)
>       at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3021)
>       at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3111)
>       at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3053)
>       at java.net.URI.(URI.java:588)
>       at java.net.URL.toURI(URL.java:946)

I guess the problem is with the string with special characters am trying to pass in the URL.

Can someone please help me to encode and send.

Answer (score 2):

As per [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2) an URL can contain only of digits, letters, and a few graphic symbols, to be more precise:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-._~:/?#[]@!$&'()*+,;=
```

any other characters, i.e. `{` and `}` must be [URL-encoded](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

If you need to use JSON structure as a part of URL query string you need to wrap it into [__urlEncode() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__urlencode) like:

```
${__urlencode(metadata={"occasion":[{"metavalue":"day-casual"}]\,"fit":[{"metavalue":"slim"}]})}
```

Check out [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) article to get familiarized with the JMeter Functions concept.

Comment: I tried using the above syntax, but am still getting error.  `java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 211: productId=0004cdacf29b4168a7a0f2c9c4ea3e56&channel=test&majorSince=1&minorSince=0&majorUntil=7&minorUntil=9999&gender=Women&{__urlencode(metadata={"occasion":[{"metavalue":"day-casual"}],"fit":[{"metavalue":"slim"}]}&category_name=skirts
 at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848)
 at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3021)
 at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3111)
 at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3053)`